# How to install TWRP or any custom recovery for a device that's not listed?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp

My phone is Tecno Camon 15 Pro, and I cannot find any custom recovery for my device. (e.g. TWRP, OrangeFox, Pitch Black, or others). How do I install a custom recovery on this or any such device for which it's not available?

There are tutorials like https://kitikus.com/how-to-install-twrp-custom-recovery-on-tecno-camon-15-pro/, but I am too afraid to try as I have bricked my device once before. Or do I have to accept the fact that it's not possible for devices not listed there?

Comment: If your device is not listed u can port a recovery from a device having same chipset like mediatek mt6582 if anything went wrong phone will boot loop so make sure to have a stock recovery and Rom image in pc

Comment: The problem is if u want to Install custom Roms and they aren't available then u have to build from sources at own

Comment: try to port TWRP from Camon 12 (Helio P35 is most likely just a overclocked Helio P22)

Comment: Its not available for Camon 12 either

Answer (score -1):

You have to [extract the stock ROM](https://techsbyte.com/how-to-extract-your-stock-firmware-from-your-android-device/) first and then port TWRP for your device.

You can follow [this](https://techsbyte.com/how-to-port-twrp-for-mediatek-android-devices/) or [this guide](https://www.droidwin.com/create-port-twrp-recovery-android/).

Comment: Your post mainly consists of external links. If the linked web pages go down or the URL changes then your answer will be useless. Therefore always quote the important info from external sites when linking them.